# hibernate PreUpdate, PreDelete and PrePersit simulation

Tags: java, hibernate, events

i'm using hibernate with SESSION, i know that @PreUpdate etc.. doesn't work with session, so i'm using hibernate event to simulate it.

But i have some problems, i use saveOrUpdate to persist an entity, so hibernate manage the save or the update for me, but i think in this way the only event fired is onSaveOrUpdate event of DefaultSaveOrUpdateListener and i can't know what kind of event is firing: save or update?

My goal is to set lastModified date, creation date and deletion date, so i need to know what type of event is firing.

Is this possible?

I try to use DefaultUpdateEventListener and DefaultSaveEventListener, but no event are firing whit those.

If i use PreUpdateEventListener and PreInsertEventListener all event are fired good, but i don't know how set field of my entity during event.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage it in DAO save, update and delete methods.